# What JSON gem should I use in a Rails 3.1 project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-3.1, yajl

The [release notes](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2011/8/31/rails-3-1-0-has-been-released) say:

> JSON decoding now uses the multi_json gem which also vendors a json
>   engine called OkJson. The yaml backend has been removed in favor of
>   OkJson as a default engine for 1.8.x, while the built in 1.9.x json
>   implementation will be used by default.

Yet when I generate a new rails 3.1 project, **Gemfile** has the **json** gem, not the **multi_json** or **OkJson** gem.

Additionally, the release notes kind of make it sound like json support is built in and doesn't need to be provided with a gem.

Also, I thought [yajl-ruby](https://github.com/brianmario/yajl-ruby) was all-the-rage with the kids these days.

What does it all mean??

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, it depends on your needs.  What do you need JSON support for?  Rails 3 does have JSON support baked in, but you might want something better for extremely large data sets.  If you are just accepting JSON-encoded post bodies or returning json data for a light-weight REST interface, then the baked in stuff will probably meet your needs.

Comment: thanks for the response -- it doesn't really answer my question though... i guess you are implying that if i left the json gem out, i would still have all the json functionality i know and love?

Comment: There's one way to find out.  Remove `gem 'json'` from your Gemfile, run `bundle update` and restart your server. ;-)

Comment: Yes but... I don't know if I'm losing anything or what I'm losing, and I don't know why rails includes the json gem in the default bundle when rails has internal json functionality...  wanna update your answer with this stuff and i'll mark it correct?